How to obtain Thermal index (TI) from landsat 8 or 9 images and then overlay them over shadow Index (SI) to obtain advanced shadow index?
I was trying to figure out the forest canopy density of a region through the methodology which I have found in certain papers such as

"INVESTIGATION OF FOREST CANOPY DENSITY CHANGES IN HYRCANIAN FOREST RESOURCES DURING 1987 TO 2002 USING REMOTE SENSING TECHNOLOGY"  and

"Assessing spatiotemporal health of forest cover using forest canopy density model and forest fragmentation approach in Sundarban reserve forest, India"


and then I'm stuck with two processes of calculating the scaled shadow index and how to obtain it.
